# How to get this list with a terse method

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have like

`{a,b}`

and I want to get

```
 {{a+1,b},{a-1,b},{a,b+1},{a,b-1}}
```

We don't care about the ordering of the list.Such as the `{{a-1,b},{a+1,b},{a,b+1},{a,b-1}}` also is a valid list.

This is current method

```
MapAt[Reverse, 
 Transpose[{Distribute[Unevaluated@Plus[{1, -1}, {a, b}], List], 
   Riffle[{b, b}, {a, a}]}], {{2}, {4}}]
```

> {{1+a,b},{a,1+b},{-1+a,b},{a,-1+b}}

Or this

```
Catenate@({Tuples[{Plus[#, {1, -1}], {#2}}], 
     Tuples[{{#}, Plus[#2, {1, -1}]}]} & @@ {a, b})
```

> {{1+a,b},{-1+a,b},{a,1+b},{a,-1+b}}

Very ugly code.Are there more beautiful solution can do this?

Comment: `lis = {{1, 0}, {-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, -1}}; {a, b} + # & /@ lis`

Comment: ...or `{a, b} + # & /@ Join[#, -#] &[IdentityMatrix[2]]`. Replace `Join[]` with `Riffle[]` if desired.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, much nicer.

Comment: `Table[{a, b}, 4] + Join[#, -#] &[IdentityMatrix[2]]`

Comment: @RunnyKine Thanks a lots. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following approach will be very fast for large lists since it utilizes vectorization:

```
Table[{a, b}, 4] + Join[#, -#] &[IdentityMatrix[2]]
```

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun:

```
Join @@ (# + {a, b} & /@ {#, -#} & /@ {{1, 0}, {0, 1}})
```

Comment: Thanks.`Catenate[# + {a, b} & /@ {#, -#} & /@ {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}]`

Answer (score 4):

A double `Transpose` might be considered "beautiful", and it certainly can be very fast too.

```
Transpose[Transpose[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}}] + {a, b}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Not as fast as some of the other methods, but a [`TranslationTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TranslationTransform) approach is also possible:

```
TranslationTransform[{a,b}][{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}}]
```

> {{-1 + a, b}, {1 + a, b}, {a, -1 + b}, {a, 1 + b}}

Answer (score 2):

```
  list = {a, b};     
  Partition[Flatten@Table[ReplacePart[
          list, i -> list[[i]] + #] & /@ {1, -1}, {i, 1, 2}], 2]

  (*{{1 + a, b}, {-1 + a, b}, {a, 1 + b}, {a, -1 + b}}*)
```